# How to retrieve and use information from other class which is not inherit monoBehaviour?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a class which acts as a database, then I create an array of the database class inside other class.
Then I fill the array, but then I can't retrieve them. What should I do?

To be precise, I want to make use of this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E2jAMc_Zk1U

What to do?
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please include your code into your question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access an array of objects by calling the index. It looks like you want to get an object that you had constructed in a class and placed into an object array.

The Jobs[] array that was initialized in the video is filled by constructing Job() objects and appending them with the `new Job()` line.

To retrieve the Job object you had appended you just need to call the index in the array like `Jobs[0]`.

Comment: It works, thank you!
So it's not accessing the class directly, but rather creating a new one inside another class. Sorry if it's quite basic knowledge, still learning about this whole concept.

Comment: @BillySantoso Think of it as constructing an object and the parameters are the traits of your object. When you make a new object you are shoving them into an array which in your case is in another class by referencing the object class constructor. I’d put the new objects inside of a List() object because you can then access its methods with a little more control in a database type class.